# how to solve this type error :super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

[image]
help me to solve the issue it asks the paramet

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit  from other class(extends) you need to use the super() on the contractor.

```
class myClass extends otherClass {
    constractor() {
        super()
    }
}
```